# Is there a way to programmatically hide all other apps besides a specific app?

Tags: macos, cocoa

I have an instance of `NSRunningApplication` and I want to hide all other apps besides that one. How can I do this? Currently I am simply iterating through all applications in `[NSWorkspace runningApplications]` and hiding each one that isn't the one I want shown, but is there a better solution?

Comment: The way you're doing it sounds like the way I'd do it.

Comment: @Moritz That doesn't do what I want.